# How can I prevent firefox from updating?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, firefox

I have firefox 56, but it keeps updating to firefox 57. Firefox 57 has severe performance related issues, and breaks my add-ons, and therefore I do not want it. Firefox 56 however seems to update against my will, and I want that to stop. How can I tell Firefox 56 to not update, not update without asking, or never look for updates.

I have not run `sudo apt-get update`, or `sudo apt-get upgrade`, but the NEW firefox keeps showing up.

Perhaps as a separate question, how can I tell `apt-get` to ignore new packages for firefox?

I have removed firefox and installed FF56 from source several times now, and it's getting obnoxious.

why is this thread different from the listed duplicates?
well, firefox has an integrated updater, in the software that pushes new versions, independently of the Ubuntu OS package management system.

as an update, I figured out that by changing the "updater" executable in the source folder's name to "_updater", functionally prevents the unwanted update from occurring, although unwanted messages regarding an available update still occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Firefox from updating to a newer version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974715/how-can-i-prevent-firefox-from-updating-to-a-newer-version). In general 
[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: sudo apt-mark hold firefox

Comment: Ubuntu is configured by default to silently download and install security updates, and new Firefox versions are always considered security updates. This is what is happening. So you must do `sudo apt-mark hold firefox` as pointed above, or disable automatic security updates (bad idea).

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is a separate issue. The OS software updater is not the problem, or is it the solution. firefox has an integrated package updater that operates independently of the OS package management system. The listed solutions therefore do not solve the problem.  I changed the firefox-integrated updater's name, and this prevents the update from occurring, but it doesn't halt the annoying messages.