# Ubuntu MATE 16 on Raspberry Pi 3, /boot partition too small

Tags: apt, partitioning, disk-usage, mate

I just installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.2 on my Raspberry Pi 3, which is the offered version on the [official site](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).  I'm testing it out to see if I can rely on it as a primary home computer.  After encountering two [annoying](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1572956) [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974715/how-can-i-prevent-firefox-from-updating-to-a-newer-version) I have things basically working, but now it's time for regular package upgrades and it seems the `/boot` partition is too small.

Just today there is a security update that requires something under 50MB of space in `/boot`, which should be no big deal, but the partition is just barely too small.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      122895564 4020112 118859068   4% /
devtmpfs          469532       0    469532   0% /dev
tmpfs             473864   19476    454388   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs             473864   12800    461064   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             473864       0    473864   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     64456   21320     43136  34% /boot
tmpfs              94776      36     94740   1% /run/user/1000
```

Below is the complete contents of `/boot`.  Can any of the larger files be safely deleted?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:/boot$ ls -la
total 20508
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   16384 jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root    4096 maí 21 05:22 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   14010 des 19  2016 bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   14273 des 19  2016 bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   13964 des 19  2016 bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   15356 des 19  2016 bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   15992 des 19  2016 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   15350 des 19  2016 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   17932 des 19  2016 bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     181 jan  1  1980 cmdline.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   36783 feb 11  2017 config.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   18693 des 19  2016 COPYING.linux
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2535 des 19  2016 fixup_cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    6622 des 19  2016 fixup.dat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    9753 des 19  2016 fixup_db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    9753 des 19  2016 fixup_x.dat
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    8192 maí 21 05:22 grub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4231256 des 19  2016 kernel7.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4130008 des 19  2016 kernel.img
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1494 des 19  2016 LICENCE.broadcom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    8192 feb 11  2017 overlays
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  634532 des 19  2016 start_cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4956996 des 19  2016 start_db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2823396 des 19  2016 start.elf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3906116 des 19  2016 start_x.elf
```

If this is near the minimum `/boot` partition occupancy, I guess the next thing would be to resize the `/boot` partition.  What is the best procedure for doing this on the Raspberry Pi + Ubuntu MATE platform?

If resizing `/boot` is impractical, can [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30130/remove-boot-partition) be followed safely on this platform to merge `/boot` into `/`?  Or is there a need to [activate experimental USB boot](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot) support to solve this problem?

(Naturally I could just try one of these, but it's taken a good bit of time to get to this point; I'd hate to have to start over.  It would be a perfectly valid answer to say, "There is no obvious reason why this or that approach should not work.")

Comment: I had this problem as well and have not yet solved it. My first inclination is to use parted or gparted to resize the partition BUT that will require booting to parted or gparted from USB as the drives cannot be unmounted while in use (I tried that last night). So I'll try booting gparted tonight and modifying the partition sizes and let you know. It's still a little baffling that so little space on a 32GB card (in my case) is dedicated to Boot AND temp space for package download, unpacking and installation.